# Owin context.Response.Body always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, owin-middleware

have followed through some samples and creating a new buffer `MemoryStream` to replace the `Response.Body` before calling next().

Below is my middleware :

```
public class TrackingMiddleware
{
    private readonly AppFunc next;

    public TrackingMiddleware(AppFunc next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env)
    {
        IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(env);

        // Buffer the response
        var stream = context.Response.Body;
        var buffer = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = buffer;

        await this.next(env);

        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
        string responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await buffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

the responsBody is always empty, event my ApiController's Action returned List of data.

Below is my Owin Startup class (Did i miss out anything ? )

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    static Startup()
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        app.Use<TrackingMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Below is my ApiController

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Json(new string[] {"123", "asdfsdf"});
    }
}
```

and My Web api configuration is registered through Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Is this the reason that messed up the sequence of the middleware?

Alternatively, if i use MVC method and it works with the `HttpContext.Current.Response` by referencing following [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1207956/Using-Owin-Middleware-for-MVC-Response-Logging)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the original stream back into the response

```
context.Response.Body = stream;
```

That way it can be read by the previous middleware in the pipeline

You would also want to dispose of any resources that are no longer needed

```
public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env) {
    IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(env);

    // Buffer the response
    var stream = context.Response.Body;
    using (var buffer = new MemoryStream()) {
        context.Response.Body = buffer;

        //call next in pipeline
        await this.next(env);

        //reset the original response body
        context.Response.Body = stream;

        //get data from buffer
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
        string responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();    
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //put data into original stream to continue the flow.
        await buffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

}
```